# Python global in module

Tags: python

I'm casually reading Python module [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html). From the doc I see I can use hashlib.md5() to call up md5. I wonder how that code works? In [hashlib.py source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/hashlib.py), it appears to me `__get_builtin_constructor` probably gets called with md5, but I don't know how the code works. Yes I can see `md5` is defined for `__all__` but how does it get there?

Comment: See [the line 1139 of hashlib.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/hashlib.py#l139): Update module dictionary using `globals()[..] = ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is here:

```
   135 for __func_name in __always_supported:
   136     # try them all, some may not work due to the OpenSSL
   137     # version not supporting that algorithm.
   138     try:
   139         globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
```

The `__get_hash` function maps to either `__get_builtin_constructor` or `__get_openssl_constructor` depending on the availability of openssl.

Let's assume openssl is not available.  This is how it would look...

The for __func_name line would iterate the keys of

```
__always_supported = ('md5', 'sha1', 'sha224', 'sha256', 'sha384', 'sha512')
```

And would add a reference to each in the module scope (globals()).  When you call `hashlib.md5()`, first it uses

```
66 def __get_builtin_constructor(name):
```

To define a callable which is returned.  In the case of `md5` it returns

```
73             return _md5.new
```

Since it is a callable that is returned, the call is then made because of the parenthesis after `hashlib.md5`.

Comment: What exactly is it doing? At the time module is imported, that code has already been run. And that code binds whatever string `__func_name` is in the dictionary the `globals()` returns to `__get_hash(__func_name)`. And when I say hashlib.md5() it goes to `__get_hash`?

Comment: And also md5() is an invocation, that's a little confusing to me.

Comment: Oh I think I can see the invocation part now. So whatever is returned by globals is THE active piece of code which resolves the object being sought in the namespace then.

Comment: @huggie: Yeah, I think you understand.  See my edits which hopefully clear it up.